# Combination with "at least" condition

Tags: combinatorics

Problem: there are 7 triangles, 13 squares, 20 circles. They must be placed in 5 distinct boxes such that  each box has at least 1 triangle and 2 squares. The order the shapes are placed in doesn't matter - just the amount in each box. All shapes must be placed in a box for it to be a valid combination. How many possible combinations are there?

My attempt: <del>For triangles each box must have 1, so there are 3 cases (0,1, or 2 boxes having an extra triangle).</del> Actually now that I'm reading it again since the boxes are distinct would it be 5C2 for the triangles? For squares and circles I'm not sure how to set up the combinations, for example there are 20 circles, but we aren't choosing 5 from them - I'm lost here.

Comment: I would have thought there might be  $15$ ways for the triangles; your latest edit has $16$

Comment: @Henry can you explain why it's 6C2?

Comment: "stars and bars" is one approach giving $6C4= 6C2$.  Alternatively you could have $5C2+5C1=6C2$

Comment: wouldn't 5C0 be a possibility though, since that still satisfies each box having at least 1 triangle?

Comment: I suspect you have to put all $7$ triangles somewhere

Comment: Place one triangle in each box.  That leaves you with two triangles to distribute to the five boxes.  You can either put both of them in the same box or place one triangle each in two of the boxes.

Comment: Assuming all shapes must be used, then it would just be 5C2, right? The problem is what to do for the other two shapes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint

You have 3 separate problems.  These types of problems are  discussed at [Stars and Bars](https://brilliant.org/wiki/integer-equations-star-and-bars/) and [Stars and Bars Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).

N.F. Taussig's comment, along with the articles, will help you set up the equation concerning the triangles.  In a similar vein, since 10 of the squares are commited to the boxes, there are 3 uncommitted squares.

You end up with three equations, each with a set number of solutions (i.e. $S_1, S_2, S_3$).  The overall answer is $S_1 \times S_2 \times S_3.$

Comment: I got up to $5C2 \times 5C3$ for triangles and squares respectively, but for circles there are 20 uncommitted circles but only 5 boxes, 5C20 doesn't make sense

Comment: @TurboAverage419 You have to study one of the first articles that I referred to in my answer, in order to correctly set up $x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_k = n$, and then determine how many solutions that it has.

Comment: Oh, would it then be $6C2 \times 7C3 \times 24C20$?

Comment: @TurboAverage419 Yes, that's it.